# Some applications become garbled and unusable

Tags: linux-mint, x11, cinnamon, qt

Over the past couple of weeks, my Linux Mint 17.2 installation has been acting up. Some programs, such as TortoiseHg, kdiff3, k3b, and some parts of Skype, become graphically corrupted and unusable. I've included a picture of TortoiseHg to show what I mean.

I suspect Qt is involved somehow, but I don't even know where to begin to troubleshoot it, or what to Google. Does anyone have any pointers? Or at least terminology to describe what I'm seeing?

[image: tortoisehg example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that openjdk has a shared memory leak which is ruining everything.:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1511395